# sns.relplot(): Set only one-side limits for facet plot

Tags: python, seaborn, limit, axes

let's assume I have the following data

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    data = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3]*4, 
                             y=list(range(12)), 
                             row_separator = ["a"]*6 + ["b"]*6, 
                             col_separator = (["a"]*3 + ["b"]*3) * 2
                            )
                       )
                        
    data
```

I'd like to have a simple line plot of `x` and `y` for each combination of `row_separator` and `col_separator`, and I want to do this using `sns.relplot()`. y-scales are different, which is fine, but I want to have the same lower bound 0 for all sub-plots.

With plt.subplots, it's like this:

```py
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

    for i in [0,1]:
        for j in [0,1]:
            ind = (data.row_separator == data.row_separator.unique()[i]) &\
                (data.col_separator == data.col_separator.unique()[j])
            axs[i,j].plot(data.loc[ind,"x"], data.loc[ind,"y"])
            axs[i,j].set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

With seaborn, I'm struggling how to do this. (My) Basis would be

```py
    g = sns.relplot(data=data,
                    x="x", 
                    y="y", 
                    col="row_separator",
                    row="col_separator",
                    kind="line"
                   )
```

I would expect `facet_kws={"ylim":(0, None)}` to do what I want, but it isn't (it's rather limiting all plots to 0 and 1).

Comment: Calling `g.set(ylim=(0, None))` in a separate step seems to do what you want.  `g = sns.relplot(...., facet_kws={"sharey":False} )` allows disabling the y-axis sharing (if needed).

Comment: Ah, of course, that works and makes sense. Thank you very much!